# How to handle common fields with relations in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am working on an e-commerce application, and using Identity for authentication and authorization. I have some common fields like `CreatedAt`, `CreatedBy` which are related to the `SiteUser` table. Is there a way to make the code less repeated?

`ICommon.cs`:

```
public interface ICommonFields
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

    public SiteUser Creator { get; set; }
    public SiteUser Updater { get; set; }
    public SiteUser Deleter { get; set; }
}
```

`SiteUser.cs`:

```
public class SiteUser : IdentityUser, ICommonFields
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? DeletedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Creator { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Updater { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeletedBy")]
    public SiteUser Deleter { get; set; }
}
```

`Address.cs`:

```
public class Address : ICommonFields
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? DeletedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

    #region Relationships
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Creator { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Updater { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeletedBy")]
    public SiteUser Deleter { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

`UserAddress.cs`:

```
[PrimaryKey("AddressId", "UserId")]
public class UserAddress : ICommonFields
{
    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string? DeletedBy { get; set; }
    [AllowNull]
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

    #region Relationships
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public SiteUser SiteUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Creator { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy")]
    public SiteUser Updater { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeletedBy")]
    public SiteUser Deleter { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Since I am inheriting from `IdentityUser`, I cannot create a concrete `CommonFields` class, since C# does not supports multiple inheritance

Comment: In short: **No**. Repetitiion of _things_ is a fact of life in business/domain software - especially in languages like C# which lack _higher-kinded-types_. [Do not be tempted to abuse OOP inheritance to gather-up common members either](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/), you'll regret it in the long-term (in fact, try to avoid inheritance alltogether). What you _can_ do, though, is make the repetition more manageable by using tooling like codegen and scaffolding (T4, etc) to take care of the drudgery for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, C# does not allow multiple inheritance, and for good reason. That doesn't mean you cannot use a base class alongside your common interface so that other entity definitions can extend the base class rather than implementing the interface. You just need your User class to be the exception, extending the interface and implementing the required common properties. So:

```
public abstract class CommonFields : ICommonFields
{
    ...
}

public class SiteUser : IdentityUser, ICommonFields
{
   ...
}

public class Address : CommonFields
{
    // Address specific properties.
}

public class SiteAddress : CommonFields
{
    // SiteAddress specific properties.
}
```

Code caring for the Common fields should accept or inspect the applicable entity by `ICommonFields` not the abstract base type, which both the sub-classes and SiteUser will comply.